# Using a webcam twice within the same application

Tags: c#, streaming, media-player, rtmp

I have a application (Wpf C#)that is using FMLE Cmd to encode a video feed *(EDIT : Video feed is from a webcam)*in h.264/MP3 and of-course stream it to a CDN. My question is - inside of my application, how can I view the RAW video feed locally and still allow FMLE to encode the stream?

I have tried the following -

Added "web" player to view the live stream from the CDN inside of the application - simulating a "live - local" view. The problem with this - is that a lot of the time the user may not have an internet connection , so this will not work.

Using a WPF media player to view the camera feed - this works great inside the applications, however, upon starting the feed, I get an error that the camera is already in use and the stream will not broadcast.

Adding a RTMP viewer, to view the local post-encode feed (Strobe playback). This allows me to view the feed and stream to my CDN, but the playback quality on the local is HORRIBLE. The funny thing about this solution was that although the local playback through Strobe was horrible, the actually FMLE broadcast was beautiful.

If you have any suggestions, questions, or advice please let me know.

Comment: how do you use FMLE from within your app?  How can your user not have an internet connection if they are streaming to a CDN?  thoughts that come to mind: use some sort of directshow splitter: http://betterlogic.com/roger/2013/05/directshow-webcam-splitter or possibly pass your video stream through ffmpeg (which saves off jpegs every so often then sends it via rtmp to fmle) or the like...gl!

Comment: I should of been clearer - It Streams to CND, AND, Records a local file.  That way even if they lose internet connection, they still have a copy of the stream. I will check into Directshow. Thanks!